# I get "Chart.JS Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'setup' ('setup' was undefined)" Error in my Blazor server app for my chart.js

Tags: c#, chart.js, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server app where I have used chart.js library for a pie chart. As soon as I open my razor page with the pie chart, I get an eception like

"Chart.JS Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'setup' ('setup' was undefined)"

I have googled a lot and I think that perhaps setup is called before its defined. It is defined in a "chart.js" in my project that I have added. I don't know if I have not called it correctly in _host.cshtml or placed it correctly in my project.

Here my code:

_Host.cshtml (related part in body section. I have all the js files in the given path. The first line chart.js is in my project where I have defined window.setup)

```
<script src="chart.js"></script>
<script src="files/js/chart.js"></script>
<script src="files/js/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="files/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="files/js/helpers.esm.js"></script>

<script src="files/js/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="files/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="files/js/helpers.mjs"></script>
<script src="files/js/chart.mjs"></script>
```

My chart.js in my project

```
window.setup = (id, config) => {
var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, config);
}
```

My razor page where the chart is

```
@page "/wmi_performance2"
@inject TagService TagService
@using System.IO
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
<Chart Id="pie1" Type="@Chart.ChartType.Pie"
   Data="@(new[] { "1", "2" })" BackgroundColor="@(new[] { "blue","green" })"
   Labels="@(new[] { "Fail","Ok" })">
</Chart>
```

My Chart.razor in the Shared/Components folder (Here I get the error when calling method setup)

```
@using System.IO
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@using Microsoft.JSInterop;
@inject IJSRuntime jsInvoker

<canvas id="@Id"></canvas>
@code {
public enum ChartType    
    {
        Pie,
        Bar
    }
    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public ChartType Type { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string[] Data { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string[] BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string[] Labels { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        // Here we create an anonymous type with all the options
        // that need to be sent to Chart.js
        
        try{

        var config = new
        {
            Type = Type.ToString().ToLower(),
            Options = new
            {
                Responsive = true,
                Scales = new
                {
                    YAxes = new[]
                {
                    new { Ticks = new {
                        BeginAtZero=true
                    } }
            }
                }
            },
            Data = new
            {
                Datasets = new[]
            {
                new { Data = Data, BackgroundColor = BackgroundColor}
        },
                Labels = Labels
            }
        };

        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setup", Id, config);
        
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText((Pages.CommonClass.error_path)))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Chart.JS Error: " + e + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a the chart.js file with the setup directly under wwwroot. Then it worked.